# VBA code to collect data from all sheets to a master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to combine my data in range(V2 to AE2) from every sheet and put it in range(A2 to J2) in the master sheet. I'm a novice and I don't have coding experience. can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub I_Voted_To_Close ()

Dim ms As Worksheet: Set ms = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet")
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim mLR As Long, wLR As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> ms.Name Then

        mLR = ms.Range("A" & ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        wLR = ws.Range("V" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        ws.Range("V2:AE" & wLR).Copy
        ms.Range("A" & mLR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```